# Remove records from Select when both conditions are met in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to get remove records from a CTE when this criterion is met -

Remove timesheets against Position ID 0000087544  and pay code is SUPA

```
select * from timesheets where ( (external_payroll_code not in ('SUPA')) and (position_id  not in ('0000087544')) )
```

is removing all records position_id = '0000087544' when i want only those position ids where external_payroll_code = 'SUPA' to be removed.

is there a way i can specify an conditional exclusion in SELECT as a subquery in Snowflake SQL or writing a JOIN clause the only way out.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

Input

| Employee ID | POSITION ID | EXTERNAL PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 0000087544 | SUPA |
| 1B | 00000888888 | SUPA |

Output

| Employee ID | POSITION ID | EXTERNAL PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1B | 00000888888 | SUPA |

Comment: I think this can be done with some AND/OR logic. Can you show us some input data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the AND/OR logic around a bit.

```
with timesheets as (select $1 employee_id, $2 position_id, $3 external_payroll_code from values ('1A',  '0000087544',   'SUPA'), ('1B', '00000888888',  'SUPA'))

select * from timesheets where not (external_payroll_code in ('SUPA') and position_id  in ('0000087544'))

EMPLOYEE_ID POSITION_ID EXTERNAL_PAYROLL_CODE
1B  00000888888 SUPA
```

Comment: Thanks Nat, for the answer, the solution works. As the team was waiting on delivery for quick fix, i added an extra column in the table as 

```

iff( (external_payroll_code = 'SUPA') and (position_id = '0000087544'), 'Y', 'N') as exclude_flag

```
and then in final cte operation only selected the records that are have exclude_flag marked as 'N'